# How can you use google ads for millions of specific keywords?

Tags: google-adsense

For example, say I have a website for dictionary definitions (100k+ words), is it possible to create a targeted ad for "hello definition" or "`<someword>` definition", so if a user searches any of the 100k+ words, they get a targeted ad with low competition? Like can you create "template" ads, where there is a variable in the keyword expression?

Or do you have to list explicitly every specific keyword you might want to use, and keep it generic, so you might have "dictionary" as a keyword instead of "hello definition"...